# mysqli_get_server_info(): invalid object or resource mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I'm getting **mysqli_get_server_info(): invalid object or resource mysqli** error, when running **wpdb** outside of wordpress in a standalone 'plugin'.

Here's the code that returns the error:

```
private $use_mysqli = false;
```

---

```
if ( function_exists( 'mysqli_connect' ) ) {
        if ( defined( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL' ) ) {
            $this->use_mysqli = ! WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL;
        } elseif ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.5', '>=' ) || 
        ! function_exists( 'mysql_connect' ) ) {
                $this->use_mysqli = true;
            } elseif ( false !== strpos( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '-' ) ) {
                $this->use_mysqli = true;
            }
        }
```

---

```
public function db_version() {
    if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
        $server_info = mysqli_get_server_info( $this->dbh );
    } else {
        $server_info = mysql_get_server_info( $this->dbh );
    }
    return preg_replace( '/[^0-9.].*/', '', $server_info );
}
```

Why am I getting this error? How should I fix it?

Comment: so what's in `$this->dbh`? Obviously it's not a mysqli object.

Comment: It's database handle in wpdb. Nevermind though, turns out it was never set properly. I'll just let everybody know right here (just so this question isn't completely useless to the community) that apparently in order to use mysqli_get_server_info, you need to use mysqli_real_connect beforehand.